# Application does not have permission to send to this device : collapsed-count: 2 in Urban Airship android

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I have working on Urban Airship for push notification with my app. After getting installed my app in device , did a test push from my Urban Airship web account. That time can receive the push notification.

But after logged into domain and user page, tried to push from same procedure of above mentioned. But couldn't get the push notification.

In the Urban Airship web account page error console shows "Application does not have permission to send to this device : collapsed-count: 2" "Original Message: Error: mismatched sender ID" error.

Could anyone help on this?

My app manifest file

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" >
</supports-screens>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

<!-- below permission added for mixpanel api -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

<!-- for cloud to device messaging -->
<permission
    android:name="com.iw.show.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.iw.show.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<application
    android:name="com.iw.show.MyApplication"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.show.SplashActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.show.DomainActivity"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.show.UploadHome"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.show.FilePickerActivity"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.show.TempMediaPlayer"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.show.UploadResult"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.show.ThumbActivity"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.show.SlideShowActivity"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.show.PreviewActivity"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.show.LoginActivity"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.show.ForgotPasswordActivity"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.show.BecomeaMemberActivity"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.show.DomainExpiredActivity"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.show.MediaPlayerActivity"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.show.ShareActivity"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.show.ShareSendAgainActivity"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.show.MenuActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.show.ViewShowList"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <data
                android:host="*.showontherun.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="*.showonthecloud.com"
                android:scheme="http" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ALL_APPS" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.show.ShowInfoPage"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.show.SupportActivity"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.sotc.show.offline.ViewOfflineShows"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.sotc.show.offline.ViewOfflineThumbActivity"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.sotc.show.offline.ViewOfflinePreviewPage"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.sotc.show.offline.SlideShowOfflineActivity"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.sotc.dialog.SaveShowDialogActivity"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="org.acra.CrashReportDialog"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@style/InfoDialog" >
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.iw.sotc.show.offline.DownloadService" >
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.iw.show.DownloadActivityPreviewActivity" >
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.iw.show.MediaPlayerService" >
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.iw.show.UploadingService" >
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.iw.show.UploadLinkService" >
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.show.UploadMedia"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_upload_media"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.show.MediaPlayer"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_media_player" >
    </activity>

    <!--
    added by Karthikeyan V 
    for managing the mixpanel api survey 






    -->
    <activity android:name="com.mixpanel.android.surveys.SurveyActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.mixpanel.android.MPConfig.AutoCheckForSurveys"
        android:value="false" />

    <!-- added for cloud to Device(C2DM)Messaging service -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.GCMReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.iw.show" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- < added by siva for play the audio by streaming > -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.iw.show.AudioStream"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    </activity>

    <!-- added for mixpanel in-app notification -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.mixpanel.android.MPConfig.AutoShowMixpanelUpdates"
        android:value="false" />

    <!-- Statring Urban Airship from here -->

    <!-- Required for the library -->
    <provider
        android:name="com.urbanairship.UrbanAirshipProvider"
        android:authorities="com.iw.show.urbanairship.provider"
        android:exported="true"
        android:multiprocess="true"
        android:permission="com.iw.show.permission.UA_DATA" />

    <!-- Required for Push -->
    <service android:name="com.urbanairship.push.PushService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.urbanairship.CoreReceiver" />
    <receiver
        android:name="com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.iw.show" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- Required for detecting when the application is upgraded so it can request a new GCM ID -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />

            <data android:scheme="com.iw.show" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- Required for analytics -->
    <service android:name="com.urbanairship.analytics.EventService" />

    <!-- Required for Rich Push -->
    <service android:name="com.urbanairship.richpush.RichPushUpdateService" />

    <!-- Required for Actions -->
    <activity android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.ActionActivity" />

    <service android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.ActionService" />

    <!-- Required for Landing Page Action -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.LandingPageActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:parentActivityName="com.iw.show.SplashActivity" >

        <!-- MODIFICATION REQUIRED set or remove the parent activity -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.iw.show.SplashActivity" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.SHOW_LANDING_PAGE_INTENT_ACTION" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <receiver android:name="com.iw.show.IntentReceiver" />

    <!-- upto the above line -->




</application>
```

And my application file
MyApplication.java

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

public static String APID = null; 
public static String TAG = "MyApplication"; 

//UsersDataSource userDataSource;

@Override
public void onCreate() {


    super.onCreate();

    //To init ACRA for getting crash report or uncaught exception

    ACRA.init(this);

    //added by Karthikeyan 
    // to implement the push notification feature
    AirshipConfigOptions options = AirshipConfigOptions.loadDefaultOptions(this);
    options.developmentAppKey = "o3uZHRo7....bYJQ";     
    options.developmentAppSecret = "u9PaC9T....OtjOw";
    options.pushServiceEnabled = true;


    options.inProduction = false; //determines which app key to use
    options.gcmSender ="12digit_Project_Number";


    UAirship.takeOff(this,options);
    PushManager.enablePush();




    APID = PushManager.shared().getAPID();
    Logger.info("APID in MyApplication :" + APID);

    PushManager.shared().setIntentReceiver(IntentReceiver.class);



    //Update the user table for APID when it has value
    /*if(APID != null)
    {
        userDataSource = new UsersDataSource(this);
        userDataSource.open();

    //  userDataSource.getAllUserIDs();

    }*/

    /*CustomPushNotificationBuilder nb = new CustomPushNotificationBuilder();

       nb.layout = R.layout.custom_notification; // The layout resource to use
       nb.layoutIconDrawableId = R.drawable.icon; // The icon you want to display
       nb.layoutIconId = R.id.icon; // The icon's layout 'id'
       nb.layoutSubjectId = R.id.subject1; // The id for the 'subject' field
       nb.layoutMessageId = R.id.message1; // The id for the 'message' field



       //set this ID to a value > 0 if you want a new notification to replace the previous one
       nb.constantNotificationId = 100;

       //set this if you want a custom sound to play
       //nb.soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+this.getPackageName()+"/" +R);

       // Set the builder
       PushManager.shared().setNotificationBuilder(nb);*/


}
```

}

And my IntentReceiver.java

```
public class IntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
// A set of actions that launch activities when a push is opened. Update
// with any custom actions that also start activities when a push is opened.
private static String[] ACTIVITY_ACTIONS = new String[] {
        DeepLinkAction.DEFAULT_REGISTRY_NAME,
        OpenExternalUrlAction.DEFAULT_REGISTRY_NAME,
        LandingPageAction.DEFAULT_REGISTRY_NAME };
public static String notify_url = null;
private String TAG = "IntentReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (Constants.DEBUG) {
        notify_url = intent.getStringExtra("shared url");
        if(notify_url != null)
        Log.d("IntentReceiver", "Intent receiver data :" + notify_url);
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Log.d("IntentReceiver", "android value in received bundle :"
                + bundle.get("com.urbanairship.push.ALERT"));
        Log.d("IntentReceiver", "Json possible data 1:" + bundle);
        Log.d("IntentReceiver",
                "Json possible data 2:" + intent.getStringExtra("alert"));
        Log.d("IntentReceiver",
                "Json possible data 3:" + intent.getStringExtra("apids"));

    }
    if (Constants.DEBUG)
        Log.d("IntentReceiver", "called IntentReceiver onReceive method");

    /*for (int i = 0; i < ACTIVITY_ACTIONS.length; i++)

        if (ACTIVITY_ACTIONS[i]
                .equals(PushManager.ACTION_REGISTRATION_FINISHED)) {
            Log.i(TAG,
                    "Registration complete. APID:"
                            + intent.getStringExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_APID)
                            + ". Valid: "
                            + intent.getBooleanExtra(
                                    PushManager.EXTRA_REGISTRATION_VALID,
                                    false));
            // Notify any app-specific listeners
            MyApplication.APID = PushManager.shared().getAPID();

            if(Constants.DEBUG)
                Log.d(TAG,"APID in MyApplication in Intent Receiver :"+MyApplication.APID);

            Intent launch = new Intent(UAirship.getPackageName()
                    + PushManager.A);
            UAirship.shared().getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(launch);

        }*/

    if (PushManager.ACTION_PUSH_RECEIVED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // Push received
    } else if (PushManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_OPENED.equals(intent
            .getAction())) {

        // Push opened

        // Only launch the main activity if the payload does not contain any
        // actions that might have already opened an activity
        if(notify_url != null)
        {
            if (!ActionUtils.containsRegisteredActions(intent.getExtras(),
                    ACTIVITY_ACTIONS))
            {
                    Intent launch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    launch.setClass(context, ViewShowList.class);
                    launch.setData(Uri.parse(notify_url));
                    launch.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(launch);
            }
        }
        else 
            {
                if (!ActionUtils.containsRegisteredActions(intent.getExtras(),
                    ACTIVITY_ACTIONS)) {
                Intent launch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                launch.setClass(context, ThumbActivity.class);              
                launch.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                context.startActivity(launch);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

For your information, I have following the Urban Airship document.

Is anything missed in the above files

Comment: https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/823114-gcm-troubleshooting-guide

Answer (score 1):

When UrbanAirship registers to GCM on your behalf, it uses the 12 digit project number you supply to it and recieves a registration ID from Google. That registration ID is tied to the project number used to obtain it.

When you send a GCM message, you use an API key to connect to the GCM server (I'm not sure if you are doing it directly or via UrbanAirship, but it doesn't matter). The API key belongs to an API project that has a project number.

`mismatched sender ID` happens when you try to send a GCM message using API key belonging to project with project number A and registration ID belonging to project number B.

You probably changed the project number you are using at some point. If you did, the way to get over that is to clear the old registration IDs (that belong to the old project number) and get new ones. I'm not sure how you clean the registration IDs stored by UrbanAirship (either locally within your app's data, or in UrbanAirship server), but there must be a way.

Comment: If sender ID mismatched means , I couldn't get even a single notification. Am I right?!. But I can receive after installation of my app before moving to a particular page.Once I get into the particular page after that I can't get any notification.

Comment: Is there any limitations on using free trail account?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVe I don't know.